# PHP $_session time

Tags: php, session, time

so im creating a login page that will have a lifetime of 8 hours upon entering the password what to add in here

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
        ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","3600000000");
    } else {
        die ('Incorrect password');
    }
}
```

Comment: oh is *that* what they're asking

Comment: what i want to now is how to increase its life it seems that session.cookie_lifetime doesnt work and after sometime the sessions will be out and need to relogin again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes  .. hope it helps you